# Websphere Application Server Extension Classloader jar conflict

Tags: java, jar, websphere, classloader, websphere-7

I have 2 WebApplications in my WAS.

1. I don't have the source code of B.
2. A .jar that B uses to run, is in the same path where the Extension Classloader jars are being loaded from.

Thus this jar is being referenced in project A and it prevents my app from running because it has conflicts with the JAR that B uses.

I can't move the .jar from there because I don't have the source code to manually set a path to load that file.

Is there a way to tell Websphere not to use a specific .jar for a specific application?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure 'B' has explicit references to the jar by path, or is it just loading classes from there implicitly?  Have you tried moving it to an isolated shared library and referencing it from the WAS config for 'B'?

Comment: Yes it has a explicit reference to that path :/ ,  whats your idea with the isolated library? , im reading about it right now

Comment: Moving it to an isolated shared library would only work if it was copied to that dir as a shortcut and was being used via normal classloading.

Comment: Damn... any  other idea??

Comment: I actually think the isolated shared library approach might work, if I'm understanding the scenario correctly.  If you need A to pick up a different version of that jar, you can put it in a shared library, set the library to use an isolated class loader, and associate it with A. That will result in A finding the jar in the shared library before it attempts to delegate to the extension class loader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your information ,  i finally fixed this issue by removing te jars that where not allowing me to start, then i  started all my applications(A), the applications(A) took their own jars.  and then i modified the was classloader at execution time to re-use the negative jars, and i pasted them back in the problematic folder, then started (B).

It works as a patch and i dont recommend to do it. It made them work by now. But it will fail when WebSphere restars again but for now i´ll get the source code and modify, the jar dependencies, and re-install  B in WAS <- Thats the correct steps in order to get transparent application server re-starts when needed.